# word boundaries in abolish

Tags: substitute, plugin-vim-abolish

```
:s/\<word\>//g
```

works but

```
:S/\<word\>//g
```

doesn't

How can I get equivalent of `\<` and co in abolish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `w` flag

```
:S/word//gw
```

from help page

> Flags can be given with the -flags= option to :Abolish, or by appending them
>   after the separator to :Subvert. The flags trigger the following behaviors:
>
> I: Disable case variations (box, Box, BOX)
>    v: Match inside variable names (match my_box, myBox, but not mybox)
>    w: Match whole words (like surrounding with \< and \>)